# Initializing (static) variables when instantiating a template

Tags: c++, templates, static, initialization

The following classes are declared

```
template <typename T>
class Z
{
    static constexpr std::size_t N{0};

    static constexpr std::array<int, N> v_static{};
    const std::array<double, N> v{};
};

class X: Z<X>{};
```

There are no problems with initialization of N

```
template<>
constexpr std::size_t Z<X>::N = 3;
```

But how to instantiate v and v_static for Z< X >? The following code is not working

```
template<>
std::array<int, Z<X>::N> Z<X>::v_static = { 4, 5, 6 };

template<>
const std::array<double, Z<X>::N> Z<X>::v = {3.14, 2.7, 0.1};
```

Comment: auto is your friend there

Comment: What isn’t working about it? Is there a compiler error? If so, what is it

Comment: @lorro could you explain in more detail?

Comment: @milla Similarly to `auto i = 3;`, you can write it for `static` member variables in classes and `class` templates. There's nothing special about it, but you save mentioning the type twice.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't be initializing the same variable two times, even more because the class variables are constant. In short, you must initialize then just once.

Comment: but here you create your own variables, for each specific class Z< X >, Z < AnotherClass > ...

Comment: @milla You assign two different values to `N`. Without fixing that, my comment wouldn't work, either.